# i made an app with phonegap build but its dont show auto update on google play store

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I made a PhoneGap app with PhoneGap build but it's after that I made an update of that and upload it on google play store and its upload on version 2 but it's not showing auto-update button on google play store WHY ??
please help...
thanx

Answer (score 1):

Google Play need some time to update the apps its not fixed time but it could be few minutes to few hours,

you can check the google play console to make sure that the current active version is `2` even if it not showing auto update button on the store itself

Comment: its been 18 days since I upload version 2 and its version 2 because I change UI in that update if someone downloads that app its comes version 2 but if someone already that version 1 it's not showing update button